# Index Match with multiple row and column criteria on google sheets

Tags: excel, indexing, google-sheets, match, multiple-columns

I have a spreadsheet with 3 sheets: one for beverage purchases by month, one for fruit purchases by month and one master sheet in which I want to display a summary of the data from the other 2 sheets.

What I am trying to do is to show data in the right cell based on restaurant name (Col A), fruit or beverage type (Col B) and month (Row 2). So for example, if Juice for Restaurant 1 in Jan-18 cost 20€, I want the master sheet to display 20€ in cell C6 (see spreadsheet below).  I have tried different index matches, sumifs and array formulas, but couldn't get it right.

I have tried to research solutions, but I could not find anything that adapts to my specific case. I hope someone can help me!

Here you can find the shared spreadsheet, feel free to make trials and edit it how you like.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O3PhzAg1qRPGGHBTlphCETEBDJg8sZrVW0rVmghbVCM/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion just for the beverages:

```
=index(Beverages!$C:$L,match($B4,index(Beverages!$B:$B,match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:index($A:$A,row()),1)),Beverages!$A:$A,0)):Beverages!$B$100,0)+match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:index($A:$A,row()),1)),Beverages!$A:$A,0)-1,match(C$2,Beverages!$C$2:$L$2,0))
```

**Edit**

This can be simplified (don't need one of the Index's)

```
=index(Beverages!$C:$L,match($B4,index(Beverages!$B:$B,match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1)),Beverages!$A:$A,0)):Beverages!$B$100,0)+match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1)),Beverages!$A:$A,0)-1,match(C$2,Beverages!$C$2:$L$2,0))
```

**Explanation**

(1) Find which restaurant you're currently dealing with:

```
index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1))
```

It only searches down as far as the current row, for the last non-blank cell it can find in column A.

(2) Find the row where this restaurant starts in the Beverages sheet:

```
match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1)),Beverages!$A:$A,0)
```

(3) Now match the beverage name in the beverages sheet:

```
match($B4,index(Beverages!$B:$B,match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1)),Beverages!$A:$A,0)):Beverages!$B$100,0)
```

(4) But you still have to add the starting position of the search back in (because you didn't start at the top):

```
match($B4,index(Beverages!$B:$B,match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1)),Beverages!$A:$A,0)):Beverages!$B$100,0)+match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1))
```

This whole thing gives the row that you want in the beverages sheet.

(5) You can get the column in the beverages sheet just by matching the corresponding month from row 2:

```
match(C$2,Beverages!$C$2:$L$2,0)
```

(or if the months matched up, you could just have pulled it across).

So the whole thing with Beverages and Fruit would be

```
=iferror(index(Beverages!$C:$L,match($B4,index(Beverages!$B:$B,match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1)),Beverages!$A:$A,0)):Beverages!$B$100,0)+match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1)),Beverages!$A:$A,0)-1,match(C$2,Beverages!$C$2:$L$2,0))
,index(Fruit!$C:$L,match($B4,index(Fruit!$B:$B,match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1)),Fruit!$A:$A,0)):Fruit!$B$100,0)+match(index($A:$A,match("zzz",$A$1:$A4,1)),Fruit!$A:$A,0)-1,match(C$2,Fruit!$C$2:$L$2,0)))
```

Comment: It gives me a formula parse error for both. 

Could you maybe try and explain what you were trying to do? The formula is a bit confusing

Comment: It seems that the separator character in your locale is a ; (semicolon) instead of a comma. Have tried the formula in a few cells of your test sheet - will try and add some explanation later.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to do this manually. For the example

> if Juice for Restaurant 1 in Jan-18 cost 20€, I want the master sheet
>   to display 20€ in cell C6

just put `=Beverages!C7`in C6.

You can do this manually for all of `gen-18` then drag them across horizontally using auto-fill for the remaining month.`enter code here`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about this solution too, but it doesn't work very well as in my actual sheet (not this example one I shared) there are various subcategories that i do not want to be included in the master sheet

Comment: OK I knew was simplistic but maybe explain a bit more what you need and provide an example of the categories you want excluded - if not solved yet.